# SoftLayer: object storage API over 5k directories show / upload limitation?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, object-storage

When I create a folder in the 5k or more folders in the container.

after few min, there is no folders.

is issue was API list constraints?

(ex. limitation 5k directories per 1 API request)

i can see folders on SoftlayerPortal (web browse-based object viewer).

but I can't see folders on API request.(cloudfuse)

containter -> folder 1 -> folder 2 -> folder 3

i'd like to make "folder 3" level folder 9k directories

Answer (score 0):

I did some tests with object storage api using 
[SoftLayer Object Storage PHP Client](https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-object-storage-php) and through REST calls, I was able to create the **9k directories** in the **"folder 3" level**.

And also was able to get the directories and files (that I created to test),  I didn't have any issue to interact with the object storage through API.

Probably it can be something related with **cloudfuse**, I can recommend to use any language supported by SoftLayer Object Storage API:

- [An Introduction to Object
  Storage](http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Introduction-Object-Storage)

Or make some tests through Rest calls:

- [Managing SoftLayer Object Storage Through REST
  APIs](http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/waelriac/managing-softlayer-object-storage-through-rest-apis)

> **Updated**

I made double check and I verified that it works fine through [Control Portal](https://control.softlayer.com/) and API. I recommend to test making REST requests, if the directories were not displayed, submit a ticket to SoftLayer for further assistance.

Comment: thank you for answer. I will make test REST request tool.